# Setup webpack to require a file in end-user application

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

If I'm developing a node module like this:

```
// index.js in library
const loadRoutes = () => require('./routes.js')
export default loadRoutes
```

Then bundle it using webpack:

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },
  mode: 'development'
}
```

Then in end-user application, when I import the library, I want `require('./routes.js')` to require `routes.js` relative to the app.

```
import loadRoutes from 'myLib'
loadRoutes()
```

But it throws an exception: `Can not find module './routes.js'`.

I tried to use [webpack ignore plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/ignore-plugin/). But it's not working in the way I expected. Webpack configuration is:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/routes\.js/)
  ],
  mode: 'development'
}
```

I don't know why such a useful thing should be that hard to be implemented in webpack. Am I doing it wrong? or what?

Comment: have you tried __non_webpack_require?