# React | import images from URL-holding variables - why am I getting wrong paths?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I read a bit about answers but haven't found something that's what I'm looking for. Please refer me to a relevant question and delete my question if it's after all a duplicate.

I've got the following file structures:

- `components`

  - `icons`

    - `bitcoin_icon.png`
    - `ethereum_icon.png`
    - ...
  - [CoinsList.js](https://pastebin.com/DGbrT2HV)
  - [CoinsTable.js](https://pastebin.com/cFSjU7Dz)

As seen in the code, I have in `CoinsTable` an array of objects called `supportedCoins`, whose elements are CryptoCoin objects, and those have the property `iconURL` which stores the path of images (which are icons).

As seen in the code, in `Coinstable.js` I have code that renders a table that displays all the elements of `supportedCoins`, each property separately, using their object properties (e.g `supportedCoins['bitcoin'].symbol`), but when trying to render the following for a CryptoCoin, for example, again with `supportedCoins['bitcoin']`:
`<img src={supportedCoins['bitcoin'].iconURL`, the rendered src *is the actual path*, but React doesn't render the picture.

That's what I want to do and what I want for to work.

What I found out that does work is doing the following to do in `CoinsTable.js`:

1. Import the icon from the right path, for example:
   `import biticonURL from './coins_icons/bitcoin_icon.png` - same path as the one in supportedCoins['bitcoin'].iconURL`
2. Create an image as desired, only with `src={biticonURL}`:
   `

To compare the different things I tried, here are the resulted `src`s of supportedCoins['bitcoin']:
 - With `supportedCoins['bitcoin'].iconURL`: `./coins_icons///bitcoin_icon.png`
 - With `bitcoinIcon`(`import`): `/static/media/bitcoin_icon.b6168699.png`

Why am I getting wrong paths, and why does store my pictures there? The images aren't stored on my server in those paths.

Comment: Can you please post the code from `list.js`? This isn't enough information to give you a good answer.

Comment: When you debug - and you breakpoint at the render function - Do you have what you need in the obj_list?

Comment: @chenop When I debug what code? Using `obj_list['whatever_key'].icoURL`?

Comment: @AlexM I added links to my original code and updated the post.

Comment: When you tried `<img src={obj_list['whatever_element_id'].iconURL}/>`, what exactly didn't work?

Comment: @jdupont I updated the post, please take a look. There's an answer to your question there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why am I getting wrong paths with triple forward slashes?

You're getting the `./coins_icons///bitcoin_icon.png` path because of how you concatenate strings in `CoinsList.js`. Here's the relevant code:

```
const coinsIconsDir = './coins_icons/';
supportedCoins['bitcoin'] = new CryptoCoin ('BTC', 'Bitcoin', coinsIconsDir + '/' + '/bitcoin_icon.png');
```

Notice that there is one forward slash at the end of `coinsIconsDir`, one as a single character, and one at the beginning of `'/bitcoin_icon.png'`, which is why you're getting that triple slash. The simplest way to fix that is to just pick one consistent place for the forward slash, like the following for example:

```
const coinsIconsDir = './coins_icons';
supportedCoins['bitcoin'] = new CryptoCoin ('BTC', 'Bitcoin', `${coinsIconsDir}/bitcoin_icon.png`);
```

Now your path will be `./coins_icons/bitcoin_icon.png` as desired.

## Why are my pictures stored under the `static/media/` path?

You're using a build and bundle system to run your app. That system is taking the resources you are importing and storing them under the `static/media/` folder before running your web app. Based on the `static/media/` path, I'm guessing that you're using `create-react-app`, which will take images and other static assets and place them in a static folder in the final build. That's described [here in the documentation](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-images-fonts-and-files). The most relevant lines are

> Webpack finds all relative module references in CSS (they start with ./) and replaces them with the final paths from the compiled bundle.
>
> This ensures that when the project is built, Webpack will correctly move the images into the build folder, and provide us with correct paths.

## So what does that mean for your case?

I'm going to give you a number of alternatives for importing images and you can pick the one you like best.

If you fix the forward slashes, you should be able to use:

```
<img src={supportedCoins['bitcoin'].iconURL} style={{maxHeight:'25px'}}/>
```

However, if `./coins_icons/bitcoin_icon.png` is not publicly available on your server (which is probably the case if you're using `create-react-app`), this will not work.

In that case, you'll either need to put the image somewhere that's publicly available (in `create-react-app` that's the [public folder](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#using-the-public-folder)), or continue to `import` them as you are doing. There are several different ways to `import`, including using the syntax you currently have:

```
import bitcoinIcon from './coins_icons/bitcoin_icon.png';
```

If you're using `Webpack`, you can also use `require`. Note that `require` [needs at least some file path information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42797313/webpack-dynamic-module-loader-by-require), so you'll need to do the file path construction inside the `require`.

```
// Assuming supportedCoins['bitcoin'].iconName has been initialized to the icon's file name
// e.g., supportedCoins['bitcoin'].iconName === bitcoin_icon.png
<img src={require(`./coins_icons/${supportedCoins['bitcoin'].iconName}`)} style={{maxHeight:'25px'}}/>
```

However, [requires outside of the top level](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/global-require)
and [dynamic requires](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-dynamic-require.md) can be considered bad practice. To avoid that you could change `CoinsList.js` to:

```
import bitcoinIcon from './coins_icons/bitcoin_icon.png';
import ethereumIcon from './coins_icons/ethereum_icon.png';
import dashIcon from './coins_icons/dash_icon.png';
import iotaIcon from './coins_icons/iota_icon.png';

var supportedCoins = new Array();
const coinsIconsDir = './coins_icons/';
supportedCoins['bitcoin'] = new CryptoCoin ('BTC', 'Bitcoin', bitcoinIcon);
supportedCoins['ethereum'] = new CryptoCoin('ETH', 'Ethereum', ethereumIcon);
supportedCoins['dash'] = new CryptoCoin('DASH', 'Dash', dashIcon);
supportedCoins['iota'] = new CryptoCoin('IOTA', 'IOTA', iotaIcon);
```

and then in `CoinsTable.js` do:

```
<img src={supportedCoins['bitcoin'].iconURL} style={{maxHeight:'25px'}}/>
```

I'd pick this last option because it keeps the coin definition contained inside one file and keeps all imports static.

Comment: Your analysis and guessing were spot-on!

I did use `react-create-app`. :)

The `require()` option didn't work for me. I got an error when I used it:
`Error: Cannot find module "."`
Shouldn't it have worked if I used `react-create-app`?

Comment: Ah shoot, you're right. I tested the webpack `require` with a string literal but not a variable, and variables do not work as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42797313/webpack-dynamic-module-loader-by-require). Give me a minute to update my answer.

Comment: Putting the `coinsIcons` folder in the `public` folder and then just giving paths: `/coinsIcons.whateverIcon` worked like a charm! So thanks so very much! I've been stuck on this.

But I'm not going to accept your answer just yet, as I want to webpack to take care of this for me, along with all the other files, and your solution doesn't provide that.

Comment: As far as I am aware, your choices are placing the images in the `public` folder or handling the imports yourself as shown above. If you find a better solution please let me know. Happy coding!

Comment: Alright, I'll accept your answer and create a post about Webpack specifically.

Thanks a lot! It works fully with your solution. :)

Comment: If you make another question make sure to specify that you're using `create-react-app` because that affects the Webpack features you have access to. Good luck!