# How to use "require" dynamically in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I have a javascript function in "sample.js" file. It is like this:

`var mapDict = { '100': 'test_100.js', '200': 'test_200_API.js', '300': 'test_300_API.js'  }`

```
function mapAPI()
{
    this.version = 0.1;
}

mapAPI.prototype.getFileName = function( id ) {
   return mapDict[id]
}

module.exports = mapAPI;
```

in another file named "institute.js" I want to require the above "test_xxx_API" files dynamically. I have the following code:

```
const mapAPI  = require('../../sample.js');
const map     = new mapAPI();
const mapFile = map.getFileName("100");
var insAPI    = require(mapFile);
```

When I run this code by "node institute.js" command, I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './test_100_API.js'.
```

But the "test_100_API.js" file exists and is located in the current folder besides "institute.js". When I changed `var insAPI = require(mapFile);` to `var insAPI = require("./test_100_API.js");` and give it the exact path instead of dynamic path, it works fine. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: where in the disk are these dynamic files found, you nee dto include the full path, for example `require(__dirname+mapFile);` if on same folder else find the path they are under NOT just the filename the WHOLE path.

Comment: then use this `require('./'+mapFile);`

Comment: They are on the same folder. My problem is that when I use `var insAPI = require(mapFile)` and prints `mapFile` value it is exactly prints `./test_100_API.js' in the console. My code works correctly with `var insAPI = require("./test_100_API.js")` but gives me error with `var insAPI = require(mapFile);`. This is the strange part.

Comment: Take a look at this thread [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42797313/webpack-dynamic-module-loader-by-require)

But in resume what you have to do is **require(\`./${path}/file.js\`);**

Comment: @NikosM., this approach is not working in react native.