# How can I update path of dynamic import while running watch mode

Tags: webpack

I have moduleA which dynamically imports moduleB. When I am running watch mode and make a change in moduleB, the chunk reference in moduleA is not updated. How can this be solved?

At the moment the only solution is to rebuild the whole project or make a change in moduleA after a change in moduleB so it regenerates moduleA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [webpack dynamic module loader by require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42797313/webpack-dynamic-module-loader-by-require)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the problem above. A full build results in a working project, the problem is when running in watch mode and a change is made in moduleB.