# How to require images inside pug each loop from an array (webpack)

Tags: webpack, pug-loader

I'm trying to iterate an array with a pug loop. I use webpack and I have some problems requiring the images.

If I require the image from a string (not a variable).

```
img(src=require('images/1.png'))
```

It works fine, but when I call it from the array

```
each image in featuredImages
   .random__item.random__item--active(class=image.size)
      img(src=require(image.thumb))
```

I get this error from webpack.

```
ERROR in Template execution failed: Error: Cannot find module 'images/1.png'
```

I don't know what is happening with the require. Any ideas? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

*This issue is related to webpack and not pug-loader.*

## **There is 2 types of require.**

### The first type is **static require**.

`img(src=require('images/1.png'))` works well because the path to the asset (*1.png*) will never change and the file path can be known without any execution or compilation of the code.

### The second type is [**dynamic require**](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-with-expression).

It's dynamic when a `require()` contains an expression rather than a string literal, so the exact module is not known on compile time. This is what you aimed when writing `img(src=require(image.thumb))`.

Unfortunately, **by design webpack doesn't support a variable as argument**, it must be a string or a string concatenation. In this case, webpack will warn the user with `Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression`. This is further explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42804941/6451730).

## Solution

The idea is to create an expression with our variable.
We can either write :

- `img(src=require(image.thumb +''))`
- `` img(src=require(`{image.thumb}`)) ``
- `img(src=require('images/' + image.thumb))`

But be aware of the bundle size output as the first two will require every files of your projet as webpack will require every files that match `.*`. Whereas the last one will only match 'images/.*'