# Require with prop doesn't work. "Invalid call at.."

Tags: javascript, image, react-native, require

I don't understand why this code doesn't work.

```
const UserCard = props => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.card}>
          <View style={{flex: 0.33}}>
            <Image source={require(props.user.image)} style={{width: 100, height: 100}}/>
          </View>
          <View style={{flex: 0.66}}>
            <Text>bb</Text>
          </View>
      </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  card: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: 'green'
  },
});


export default UserCard;
```

props.user.image = 'Assets/test/joan.jpg'

If I put in an image:

`<Image source={require('Assets/test/joan.jpg')} style={{width: 100, height: 100}}/>`

It's works.

In assets I have package.json with name Assets so I can use absolute paths.

I have test various options and none of them.

For example:

```
return (
   const user_image = require(props.user.image);
   ... 
      <Image source={user_image} style={{width: 100, height: 100}}/>
   ...
```

Other:

```
return (
   const user_image = props.user.image;
   ... 
      <Image source={require(user_image)} style={{width: 100, height: 100}}/>
   ...
```

Or with src instead of source, but it doesn't work...

Also I test it changing
`const UserCard = props => {`

For
`class UserCard extends React.Component {`

And still the same...

Please help.

EDIT:

HomeScreen with object users

```
const users = [
      {
        "image" : "Assets/test/fernando.jpg",
        "name" : "Fernando",
        "description" : "General Manager",
      },
      {
        "image" : "Assets/test/daniel.jpg",
        "name" : "Daniel",
        "description" : "CEO",
      },
      {
        "image" : "Assets/test/joan.jpg",
        "name" : "Joan",
        "description" : "Manager",
      },
    ];

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
   ...
   render() {
       return (
         <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
           <ScrollView
             style={styles.container}
             contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>
             { typeof users === 'object' && users.length > 0 && (users.map((user, index) => {
              return (
                  <View key={index} style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
                    <UserCard user={user} />
                  </View>
              )})
            ) }  
           </ScrollView>
         </SafeAreaView>
       );
     }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42797313/438992

Comment: Can you tell us how you passing `user` in your `UserCard` component?

Comment: @KishanBharda I edit code for you see the variable user

Comment: @Cookie for static image I don't know about it. But one more question is `UserCard` component is in another file ?

Comment: yes @KishanBharda

Comment: So there may be path issue @Cookie ?

Comment: No, because the other params show well.
For example: <Text>{props.user.name}</Text>
 @KishanBharda

Comment: No, I mean path issue for image.

Comment: I will look at it but I think I made a console.warn of props.image and it was the same as I put static "Assets/test/joan.jpg" @KishanBharda

Answer (score 0):

So today I ran into this problem
My solution was instead of passing the path to the require like this

```
<Image source={require(props.user.image)} />
```

I passed it like this

```
<Image source={props.user.image} />
```

And I sent require with the Data like this

```
const users = [
      {
        "image" : require("Assets/test/fernando.jpg"),
        "name" : "Fernando",
        "description" : "General Manager",
      },
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

This can be other solution. Don't send image path from parent component to child component  . Send image itself like that :

```
<UserCard user={user} image={require('Assets/test/daniel.jpg')} />
```

And Use it with directly in child component:

```
<Image source={props.image} style={{width: 100, height: 100}}/>
```