# Dynamic module import in component for gatsby js site

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am building a gatsby site where each page is generated from a template, but each page requires a different module import.

Specifically, each page contains an [observablehq notebook](https://observablehq.com), and these are exported from observable as modules. See [here](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/downloading-and-embedding-notebooks).

The pages are dynamically generated from a `json` file like:

```
[
    {   "path": "page1",
        "modulename": "gatsby-test"
    },
    {   
        "path": "page2",
        "modulename": "gatsby-test-2"
    }
]
```

This is done using `createPages` in `gatsby-node.js`.

I have already `yarn add`ed each notebook the project, e.g. `yarn add https://api.observablehq.com/@robinl/gatsby-test.tgz`.

I'm trying to write a component which takes the module name as a property, and then loads the right module from the contents of `this.props`.

An outline of my component looks like:

```
class ImportedNotebook extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        var promise = import(this.props.modulename).then(function(themodule) {
            // do stuff here
        })   
    }

    render() {
        return (<div>blah</div>);
    }
}
```

This does not work - I get an `Unhandled Rejection (Error): Cannot find module 'gatsby-test-2'` error when visiting the page on localhost using gatsby develop.

However, if I replace `this.props.modulename` with `"gatsby-test-2"` it works fine.

Is there a way of dynamically loading modules from a variable?  Or perhaps a different approach that would be more suitable to solve this problem?

Comment: I feel like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42797313/webpack-dynamic-module-loader-by-require) may be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I have become increasingly convinced that it's not possible to do this using this approach.  Essentially this is because webpack requires explicit import.  If you attempt to make these 'dynamic' it has no way of knowing what code to bundle.

The solution I came up with instead was:
- Develop a component that takes as an input a `notebook` imported from an observable module 
- Have a minimal individual page for each notebook that imports the notebook, and then passes it to my component

For each page, the code looks like this:

```
import React from "react"
import notebook from "gatsby-test-2"
import ObservablePage from "../components/obs_page"

export default ({ data }) => (
    ObservablePage(notebook)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your page building process correctly, you should be able to pass the observable `modulename` into the `context` of your dynamically generated pages when calling the `createPage` within `exports.createPages:`

```js
exports.createPages = function({ actions }) {
  // ...
  actions.createPage({
    path: pagePath,
    component: require.resolve("./src/templates/pageTemplate.js"), // your page template file
    context: {
      modulename: modulename, // pass in your modulename URL here
    },
  })
```

Then within your page template (`"./src/templates/pageTemplate.js"`) you can access the `modulename` variable like this:

```js
this.props.pageContext.modulename
```

Finally, you can use that variable to dynamically import each of your components.