# Unable to require() a variable path from props in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I am sending data - a URL to a local image file, from parent to child, and when I load it in child component's  it shows an error, but if I directly load it, it works.

**Code:**

> In parent.vue component's data:

```
data(){return{items:[
      {id:1, src:"../../../assets/img.png" }
```

> In child.vue component's mounted()

```
img.src = require(this.item.src); // This does not work
img.src = require("../../../assets/img.png") // This works
```

**And console.log(this.item.src) gives exactly the same string, so the child is actually getting the data correctly**

As you can see both those examples have the same URL string, but one works, one does not. I have tried every combination or relative Url but everything fails.

What's going on?

**note:** I am serving the development version via `webpack-dev-server`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem should be that `require` is handled by webpack statically during compile time, whereas the value in the prop resolves during runtime

```
img.src = require(this.item.src); // This does not work since during webpack build the path is not resolved
img.src = require("../../../assets/img.png") // This works since the image is loaded and added statically
```

See this answer for more clarity [webpack dynamic module loader by require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42797313/webpack-dynamic-module-loader-by-require)

You could try using the [dynamic import](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/lazy-loading-and-code-splitting-in-vue-js/) syntax for loading the image with a variable, but the webpack configuration [may] have to be modified, if you aren't using the vue cli

it would be something like `import(this.item.src).then(src => img.src=src)`; but should be called in the `mounted()` function, maybe