# Vue 3 use dynamic component with dynamic imports

Tags: vue.js, dynamic, import, components, vuejs3

I use Vue 3 and I have a dynamic component. It takes a prop called `componentName` so I can send any component to it. It works, kind of.

#### Part of the template

```html
<component :is="componentName" />
```

The problem is that I still need to import all the possible components. If I send `About` as a `componentName` I need to import `About.vue`.

#### Part of the script

I import all the possible components that can be added into `componentName`. With 30 possible components, it will be a long list.

```js
import About "@/components/About.vue";
import Projects from "@/components/Projects.vue";
```

### Question

It there a way to dynamically import the component used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I already faced the same situation in my [template](https://github.com/boussadjra/vue3-tailwind2) when I tried to make a demo of my icons which are more than 1k icon components so I used something like [this](https://github.com/boussadjra/vue3-tailwind2/blob/main/src/views/components-demo/Icons.vue) :

```js
import {defineAsyncComponent,defineComponent} from "vue";

const requireContext = require.context(
    "@/components", //path to components folder which are resolved automatically
    true,
    /\.vue$/i,
    "sync"
);
let componentNames= requireContext
    .keys()
    .map((file) => file.replace(/(^.\/)|(\.vue$)/g, ""));

let components= {};

componentNames.forEach((component) => { //component represents the component name
    components[component] = defineAsyncComponent(() => //import each component dynamically
        import("@/components/components/" + component + ".vue")
    );
});
export default defineComponent({
    name: "App",
    data() {
        return {
            componentNames,// you need this if you want to loop through the component names in template
         
        };
    },
    components,//ES6 shorthand of components:components or components:{...components }

});
```

learn more about [require.context](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#requirecontext)

Comment: If you have trouble resolving "require.context", you may need to import @types/webpack-env and change your tsconfig to include those types: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1276

Comment: FYI the line `import("@/components/components/" + component + ".vue")` cause Webpack to load all modules that match the pattern. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/42804941/885922 and https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import